# Jessie to Stretch upgrade ; squid proxy broken

Tags: debian, squid

I have just upgraded from Jessie to Stretch a proxy server with a perfectly working Squid configuration.

The upgrade asked me if I wanted to copy `squid.conf` from the old `/etc/squid3` directory to the new `/etc/squid` directory, and I allowed it.

Now all accesses are simply refused and logged as `TCP_DENIED`in the access log file.

My `squid.conf` file is below.

What to do?

```
hierarchy_stoplist cgi-bin ?

acl QUERY urlpath_regex cgi-bin \?
no_cache deny QUERY

cache_replacement_policy heap LFUDA
minimum_object_size 0 KB
# maximum_object_size_in_memory 8 KB
cache_dir aufs /home/squid 4000 16 256
access_log syslog:local5.info squid
cache_access_log none 
cache_log /dev/null
cache_store_log none 
pid_filename /var/run/squid3.pid

debug_options ALL,1

ftp_user proxy@xxxx.xx
# ftp_list_width 32
ftp_passive on
dns_retransmit_interval 5 seconds
dns_nameservers 8.8.8.8

acl connections maxconn 200 
http_access deny connections
negative_ttl 300 seconds

# acl manager proto cache_object # Commented out on upgrade to 3.4

acl SSL_ports port 443 563
acl Safe_ports port 80      # http
acl Safe_ports port 21      # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443 563 # https, snews
acl Safe_ports port 70      # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210     # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280     # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488     # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591     # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777     # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

acl localwww    dstdomain xxxxx
acl baddomains  dstdomain .xxxx .xxxx
#acl badhost src x.x.x.x/32
acl baddest dst x.x.x.x/24 x.x.x.x/32
acl srvnets src x.x.x.x/24 
acl pcs         src x.x.x.x/32 


acl local_machines dst 10.0.0.0/8 172.16.0.0/12 193.137.2.90
cache deny local_machines


always_direct allow all




http_access deny manager
# Deny requests to unknown ports
http_access deny !Safe_ports
# Deny CONNECT to other than SSL ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports

http_access deny baddest
http_access deny baddomains
http_access allow srvnets
http_access allow pcs
http_access deny all

icp_access deny all

miss_access deny baddest
miss_access deny baddomains
miss_access allow srvnets
miss_access allow pcs
miss_access deny all

cache_mgr alerta@xxx.xx

cache_effective_user proxy
cache_effective_group proxy


visible_hostname xxx.xxx.xx 

memory_pools on
forwarded_for on

client_db on

buffered_logs on


allow_underscore on
offline_mode off
uri_whitespace encode

half_closed_clients off


strip_query_terms off


cache_swap_high 70

shutdown_lifetime 2 seconds
refresh_all_ims on 
#client_db off
max_filedescriptors 16384
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In squid v3.5 the `hierarchy_stoplist` and `client_db` configuration directives are obsolete.

Commented them out, restarted the service and `squid` started working properly.

From [squid mailing list](http://www1.tr.squid-cache.org/mail-archive/squid-users/201210/0027.html)

> As part of the Squid configuration cleanup project hierarchy_stoplist 
>   has appeared as a directive which is almost but not quite obsolete. 
>   Points against it:
>   1) it only affects configurations with cache_peer.
>
> 2) The default settings published with earlier Squid versions are 
>   obsolete since around 3.1 version.
>
> If you are only using "hierarchy_stoplist cgi-bin \?" you can remove  it completely from any Squid-3 config file.
>
> 3) The following 
>   hierarchy_stoplist A B C    is almost exactly equivalent to:     acl
>   Foo url_regex A B C     always_direct allow Foo    With the exception
>   that never_direct is applied before  hierarchy_stoplist but not before
>   always_direct.
>
> In absence of any objections this will be scheduled for deprecation 
>   within the squid-3.4 release cycle.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same trouble after an upgrade. In my case, the error was that it couldn't get lock on the squid.pid on /var/run, although it could creat it. Well, to short a long story, as a hail mary and really unorthodox method to solve it, **I removed systemD**. That's **NOT** a recommendation, although. I got the how to remove it here (http://without-systemd.org/wiki/index.php/How_to_remove_systemd_from_a_Debian_jessie/sid_installation). The crazy thing is that it worked :)

Comment: systemd is not allowed in my Debian Linux farm; at home OS/X, FreeBSD and OpenBSD.